# Calculating the mean of two xarrays datasets is very very slow. Why?

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I have two xarray datasets that contain spatial temperature. Each has lat lon coordinates and a temperature data variable. The coordinates match. I want to combine the two datasets by calculating their averages. They do contain NaNs so the averaging needs to skip them.

The way I am doing it now is:

```
(xr1+xr2)/2
```

which is slow. I also tried

```
np.nanmean(np.dstack((xr1.temp.values,xr2.temp.values)),2)
```

The operation `np.nanmean` itself is very fast. The problem is that `.values` is very very slow. I also tried assigning one data variable from one dataset to another and then take the mean but it is also very slow. I also tried xarray merge but it doesn't work well with NaNs.

Please share any useful ideas

Comment: Are you using in-memory or on-disk arrays?

Comment: I am not sure. The data comes from a .nc file that I read using a URL.

Comment: In that case, you can give [`Dataset.load`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.load.html) a go

Comment: Perfect. It is working much much faster now. I didn't realize that the xarrays didn't contain the data yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Brian61354270 in the comments, I realized that the xarrays were linked to a URL containing the data, but it wasn't loaded yet to my computer. After using `.load` on both xarrays, the numerical operations were very fast.